# Cover the task bar with VB

Tags: vb.net

How can i make a program stay above the task bar even when it loses focus with visual basic 2008?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I have to agree with SLaks, this behavior is beyond annoying and you should be looking for some other solution.

Comment: Focus stealing is evil (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/please-dont-steal-my-focus.html), though I guess since you /had/ focus, this is really focus conversion ;).

Comment: oh god, these comments are annoying and evil. there are plenty of good reasons to want to do this, not the least of which is a security issue. add privacy, policy and kiosks and you've got many more good reasons.

Comment: Upvoting not because I care about the answer, but to cancel out the knobs who downvote just because they don't want to implement this.

Comment: @cory: exactly. just because someone has a preference in their programming model shouldn't be reason to downvote them. it's not as if Jcubed said something like *how do I hack into a mainframe?*. Upvoting him and his other threads to give him a reason to want to come back to SO after being treated like this.

Answer (score 5):

if needed in any case, one can set the TopMost property of the form to true. please think about not annoying your users :-)

[Form in front of taskbar http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/724/deactivated.jpg](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/724/deactivated.jpg).

Comment: I don't think that will help.

Comment: the task bar still covers it when you defocus it

Comment: as i said, works on .net with c# 2.0/vs2008/vista... i may help with other configuration, but first, you have to tell me :-)

Comment: I mean, it puts it ontop of other things, but not things that have topmost set to true as well

Comment: correct. thats intended :-) there is no top-topmost, sorry  :-)
the focused topmost-window is always in front of other non-focused topmost-windows. so the only thing you could do is focus your window, when it's being unfocused - but i would not recommend such a blatant behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your form and in the timer tick event simply set:

```
me.topmost = true;
```

Comment: Someone already posted this as a possible solution. The `Timer` is completely unnecessary.